# How to use the target folder of another project as target platform repository in a Tycho build?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde, p2

I am creating an Eclipse plugin in an continuous integration environment. My project contains four child modules as follows

```
parent
   ---p2Repository
   ---eclipseplugin
   ---feature
   ---updateSite
```

During the continuous integration build, first the p2 repository for the dependencies is created. My Eclipse plugin project needs to point to the `p2Repository`'s target folder to get the dependecies. But by providing the following code in the `eclipse-plugin` POM file is not working:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Dependencies</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>file:/../p2Respository/target/repository/</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Any advice?

Comment: With this solution, do you have to also set a relative URL in the target definition file? How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file URL you specified does not represent a relative path, and relative URLs are not supported in the repositories configuration.

But you can simply construct an absolute URL pointing to the sibling project's target folder by using the `${project.baseUri}` Maven property:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Dependencies</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>file:/${project.baseUri}/../p2Respository/target/repository/</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.I have a doubt .During the maven build as a pre build step the eclipseplugin  checks for the repository.But after the p2Repository project executed only the target folder will be generated with  repository.So it is pointing to empty folder.How to avoid that. As i described after the p2 repository only i need eclipse plugin to execute.